# Remove data.frame row names when using xtable

Tags: r, latex, report

OK, I admit this one is a bit uptight (read: "stupid"), and I assume it's quite easy too. I'm writing a report and I want to use `xtable` package for LaTeX table generation (note that `memisc` package does the job, but say I want to do this solely with `xtable`).

Let's use standard `mtcars` dataset and `reshape` package:

```
mdtf <- melt(mtcars, id.vars = c("am", "cyl"), measure.vars = c("mpg", "hp", "wt"))
( res <- cast(mdtf, am + cyl ~ variable, mean) )
  am cyl      mpg        hp       wt
1  0   4 22.90000  84.66667 2.935000
2  0   6 19.12500 115.25000 3.388750
3  0   8 15.05000 194.16667 4.104083
4  1   4 28.07500  81.87500 2.042250
5  1   6 20.56667 131.66667 2.755000
6  1   8 15.40000 299.50000 3.370000
```

If I wrap this inside `xtable`, I'll get row names (1..6):

```
xtable(res)
% latex table generated in R 2.13.0 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Fri Mar 25 09:40:12 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
  \hline
 & am & cyl & mpg & hp & wt \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.00 & 4.00 & 22.90 & 84.67 & 2.94 \\ 
  2 & 0.00 & 6.00 & 19.12 & 115.25 & 3.39 \\ 
  3 & 0.00 & 8.00 & 15.05 & 194.17 & 4.10 \\ 
  4 & 1.00 & 4.00 & 28.07 & 81.88 & 2.04 \\ 
  5 & 1.00 & 6.00 & 20.57 & 131.67 & 2.75 \\ 
  6 & 1.00 & 8.00 & 15.40 & 299.50 & 3.37 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Now, is there any chance that I can avoid this (in one-liner, if possible)?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Use `include.rownames=FALSE` in the `print` method.
See `?print.xtable`:

```
R> print(xtable(res), include.rownames=FALSE)

% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Fri Mar 25 10:06:08 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
am & cyl & mpg & hp & wt \\ 
  \hline
0.00 & 4.00 & 22.90 & 84.67 & 2.94 \\ 
  0.00 & 6.00 & 19.12 & 115.25 & 3.39 \\ 
  0.00 & 8.00 & 15.05 & 194.17 & 4.10 \\ 
  1.00 & 4.00 & 28.07 & 81.88 & 2.04 \\ 
  1.00 & 6.00 & 20.57 & 131.67 & 2.75 \\ 
  1.00 & 8.00 & 15.40 & 299.50 & 3.37 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: And that default `matrix` to `data.frame` conversion is really annoying. This is the only solution (workaround) to preserve `rownames`: http://www.vpihur.com/blog/?p=131 So I have to modify my function: https://gist.github.com/887249 to set `rownames` as first column. And then to beg LaTeX not to align cells on his own... damn!