# How do I remove row names when using pander to brew a report?

Tags: r, pander

I'm trying to get my head around using R to generate reports and think I have settled on trying to just use **pander**, after confusing myself with various combinations of **knitr**, **Rmarkdown**, **pander** and **reports**.

I now have two files:

'ReportIntro.brew' that contains the structure of the report

```
# My Report Title 
## Sample Information
#### <%=set.alignment('left') ; as.character(info[1,1])%>
<%=set.alignment('left') ; info[2:8,1:2]%>
```

'Report.R' to create a data.frame 'info' required for the report

```
library(pander) ; library(xlsx)
info=read.xlsx(file="info.xlsx", sheetName="info", header=FALSE)
Pandoc.brew(file="ReportIntro.brew", output=tempfile(), convert="docx")
```

This gives me my first Word document, with a table. However, it includes unwanted row and column names.
I found a blog about [generating tables with pander and knitr](http://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2013/06/generating-tables-using-pander-knitr.html), which suggested setting

```
row.names(info) <- NULL
```

but this had no effect.

If I try using

```
print(info[2:8,1:2], include.rownames=FALSE)
```

or

```
print(xtable(info[2:8,1:2]), type="html", include.rownames=FALSE)
```

as suggested in another post about [removing row names using xtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430338/remove-data-frame-row-names-when-using-xtable), the table doesn't appear at all in the Word doc.

So: how do I get my table without showing row names?

(This is my first post, so I hope it fits the requirements!)

**EDIT:** *This it the result of dput(info)*

```
> dput(info)
structure(list(X1 = c("School Information", "Name", "Type", "DfE number", 
"URN", "DfE link", "Dashboard Report", "Ofsted link", "Test Information", 
"Test Date", "Comments", "Analysis comments", "Sample Size", 
"Year group", "All", "11", "11"), X2 = c(NA, NA, "Primary, Academy, Prep, Middle etc", 
NA, "Enter school URN here", "http://www.education.gov.uk/", 
"http://dashboard.ofsted.gov.uk/", "http://www.ofsted.gov.uk", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Set", "All", "top", "middle"), X3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "M", "408", "165", 
"243"), X4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "F", "402", "145", "257"), X5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Total", "810", "310", "500")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am the author of `pander` thanks for giving it a try, @Jerubaal. It would be awesome if your could also post `info` or rather the result of `dput(info)`, so that I could reproduce your steps, but as far as I see now a workaround would be to first save that subset of `info` into a new variable, then returning that new object in a chunk.

More details: `pander` suprresses `row.names` if those are trivial, like a sequence from `1` to the number of rows. If you return a subset of a `data.frame`, you return an object with `row.names` that do not fit this basic schedule. But if you create a new `data.frame`, the automatic `row.names` would start from `1` to `nrow`.

Quick demo (please note that `pander` is run automatically on each chunk anyway):

```
> library(pander)
> pander(iris[2:3, 1:3])

---------------------------------------------------
&nbsp;   Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length 
------- -------------- ------------- --------------
 **2**       4.9             3            1.4      

 **3**       4.7            3.2           1.3      
---------------------------------------------------

> x <- iris[2:3, 1:3]
> pander(x)

---------------------------------------------------
&nbsp;   Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length 
------- -------------- ------------- --------------
 **2**       4.9             3            1.4      

 **3**       4.7            3.2           1.3      
---------------------------------------------------

> row.names(x) <- NULL
> pander(x)

-------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length 
-------------- ------------- --------------
     4.9             3            1.4      

     4.7            3.2           1.3      
-------------------------------------------
```

---

**Update**: demo with the provided `info` dataset

```
> x <- info[2:8,1:2]
> pander(x)

--------------------------------------------------------
&nbsp;         X1                      X2               
------- ---------------- -------------------------------
 **2**        Name                                      

 **3**        Type           Primary, Academy, Prep,    
                                   Middle etc           

 **4**     DfE number                                   

 **5**        URN             Enter school URN here     

 **6**      DfE link      http://www.education.gov.uk/  

 **7**  Dashboard Report http://dashboard.ofsted.gov.uk/

 **8**    Ofsted link       http://www.ofsted.gov.uk    
--------------------------------------------------------

> row.names(x) <- NULL
> pander(x)

------------------------------------------------
       X1                      X2               
---------------- -------------------------------
      Name                                      

      Type           Primary, Academy, Prep,    
                           Middle etc           

   DfE number                                   

      URN             Enter school URN here     

    DfE link      http://www.education.gov.uk/  

Dashboard Report http://dashboard.ofsted.gov.uk/

  Ofsted link       http://www.ofsted.gov.uk    
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @darozig! I have added edited my post to include the **dput(info)**. I created a new variable and although **row.names(x) <- NULL** did not appear to work, **row.names(x) <- seq_along(1:dim(x)[1])** did have the desired effect.

Comment: Sorry, I mispelt your name, @daroczig, but cannot seem to edit my comment again.

Comment: No problem, @Jerubaal :) I have also updated my answer, but it seems to work fine here with assigning `NULL`. Could you please let me know which version of `pander` are you running: with `sessionInfo()`? Please try the most recent version: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#installation

Comment: I'm running pander_0.3.8, which looks like it is the current one. @daroczig