# R hierarchy and passing arguments to correct function

Tags: r, oop

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430338/remove-data-frame-row-names-when-using-xtable) answer I can use `include.rownames=FALSE` to suppress printing row names when using `xtable` (package to convert r output to LaTeX table). E.g.:

Data:

```
> head(dataset)
  order original prediction anomaly.score abs.o.p
1     1        0          0             1       0
2     2        0          0             1       0
3     3        0          0             1       0
4     4        0          0             0       0
5     5        0          0             0       0
6     6        0          0             0       0
```

Printing with row names:

```
> xtable(head(dataset))
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.8-0 package
% Sun Dec 20 18:38:13 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrr}
  \hline
 & order & original & prediction & anomaly.score & abs.o.p \\ 
  \hline
1 &   1 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
  2 &   2 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
  3 &   3 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
  4 &   4 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
  5 &   5 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
  6 &   6 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Printing without row names:

```
> print(xtable(head(dataset)), include.rownames=FALSE)
% latex table generated in R 3.1.1 by xtable 1.8-0 package
% Sun Dec 20 18:49:34 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
  \hline
order & original & prediction & anomaly.score & abs.o.p \\ 
  \hline
  1 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
    2 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
    3 &   0 &   0 & 1.00 &   0 \\ 
    4 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
    5 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
    6 &   0 &   0 & 0.00 &   0 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see `include.rownames=FALSE` is argument for `print` function not for `xtable`. How is this possible? Isn't `xtable` just printing the results to standard output? How does `print` know what to omit when `include.rownames=FALSE` is used? Referred page also mention `?print.xtable`. What does this mean? Is `print.xtable` some special kind of print or it is `xtable` method called from package `print` or what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `print` is a generic function in `R`. Take a look at its definition:

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
```

That's it. The only thing `print` does is to find the appropriate function to pass the object it receives. That is, it is going to dispatch the object to another function according to the class of the object.

So when `print` receives an object of class `xtable`, it uses the `print.xtable` function, which is a print method for `xtable` objects. The function `print.xtable` is from the `xtable` package and it was written exactly for that purpose, so it knows how to handle those objects and understands the argument `include.rownames`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend some good reading about this. I've found those three sites: http://bit.ly/1hWRxTN http://bit.ly/1OhqHMw http://bit.ly/1Pf0Vpe but something more actual that would sum up info from this would be fine.

Comment: Maybe: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html and http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-dispatch-to-a-method-in-r.html .